# Dynamically generating input field

Tags: php

```
<? $fileUpload=3 ; for($i=0;i<$fileUpload;$i++) { ?>
    <input type="file" name="upload_file" value="" id=" " />
<? } ?>
```

I want to actually generate three file upload field based on the loop, but this code is not working.

**Actual requirement**

On the click of the browse button, if the file is selected... the next field of form should appear... automatically and so on.

Comment: Really? why a loop? 3 iteration and no variable used inside, you better copy/paste 2 times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $fileUpload=3 ; for($i=0;$i<$fileUpload;$i++) { ?>
    <input type="file" name="upload_file" value="" id=" " />
<?php } ?>
```

You needed to change "i" to "$i" in your break condition.

Also don't get into the habit of short PHP opening tags: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)